# get sets of index values, grouped by column year

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe df1

```
        date      
sample
a1      2005-08-28
b1      2005-06-23
c1      2006-01-11  
d1      ...
```

Ultimately, I want a dictionary of sets of samples, grouped by year. So something like

```
dict_y = {"2005": {a1, b2}, "2006": {c1}, ...}
```

I thought the best way to approach this would be by using pandas groupby, but I can't seem to get it work.

```
df2 = df1.reset_index()
df2 = df2.set_index([(df2["date"].dt.year)])
df3 = df2.groupby(df2.index.values)
```

But here df3 is not a dataframe neatly grouped by year, but just a "GroupBy object". What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by [`dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) lambda function where convert `index` values to `sets`. Last convert [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.Timestamp('2005-08-28 00:00:00'), 
                            pd.Timestamp('2005-06-23 00:00:00'), 
                            pd.Timestamp('2006-01-11 00:00:00')]}, index=['a1','b1','c1'])
print (df)
         date
a1 2005-08-28
b1 2005-06-23
c1 2006-01-11

df = df.groupby(df.date.dt.year).apply(lambda x: set(x.index.values)).to_dict()
print (df)
{2005: {'a1', 'b1'}, 2006: {'c1'}}
```

Comment: Works (almost) like a charm! Had to remove the .date there however, as it returned AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'date'. But without .date it works. Another thing is, it returns the years not as integers, but with one decimal, eg "2016.0". Any idea what might cause this behaviour or how to get rid of it?

Comment: I think you can remove `date`, because you have `Series`, not `DataFrame` like `df = pd.Series([pd.Timestamp('2005-08-28 00:00:00'), 
                            pd.Timestamp('2005-06-23 00:00:00'), 
                            pd.Timestamp('2006-01-11 00:00:00')], index=['a1','b1','c1'])`, so it is ok, because Series have no columns. Another problem with float can be by version of `pandas`, I test it in `0.19.2` or maybe some `NaT` values in `Series` - check it by `(df[df.isnull()])`

Answer (score 1):

Another variant using *GroupBy's* `.groups` attribute which returns a dictionary.

Convert the values of the dictionary from `pd.Index` type to a `set` later to extract unique elements out of it.

```
{k:set(v) for k,v in df.groupby(df['date'].dt.year).groups.items()}
Out[54]:
{2005: {'a1', 'b1'}, 2006: {'c1'}}
```